# Apple push notifications in rails app for POC

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I have to develop Apple push notifications service for a rails app for POC purpose. I have gone through the documentation for APNS gem and apns_on_rails gem. Now I am confused that which gem to use. I haven't worked with push notifications in rails and therefore don't want to spoil the application structure. This is the first time that I have to try. So please guide on which gem should be easier to use and implement for as a first timer. Another thing, is it the same for iPhone and iPad ?

Any help and guidance from your side is acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced with APNS gem, you can check the sample code below:

```
def self.ios_client_push(message, device_token, other = nil)
  return if device_token.blank?
  APNS.pem  = Rails.root.join('vendor/plugins/pem/YOUR-PEM.pem').to_s
  APNS.pass = 'YOUR_PASSPHARSE'
  APNS.send_notification(device_token, :alert => message, :sound => 'default', :other => other)
end
```

I think it's an easy way to push notification and there is no difference between iPhone and iPad. In the sample code, I reseted the PEM configuration each time I call it because I used 2 PEM files for pushing notification. You can set it in RAILS application configuration for the first application launching.

Comment: Hi, can I use the development certificate and test it while running the app on local machine or will I have to deploy the code on server and then test? I have don't have any separate development servers but only test and production servers for my rails app. How can I test it ?

Comment: No matter which environment you're using, just make sure that you're connecting to internet to let your rails app sends request to Apple Push Notification server. So you can use it well with your local merchant. About testing it, you must have an iOS app which can receive push notification.